# C++ function declaration problem, error C2086. Help me CPP Masters

Tags: c++, function, declaration

This is my CPP code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
/*
bool func1(int budget){
    if( budget < 0 ) {
        cout << "Budget cannot be negative."<< endl; 
        return false; 
    }
    else {
        return true; 
    }
}
bool func2(int num1, int num2, int num3){ 
    if (int num1 < 0 || int num2 < 0 || int num3 < 0 ) {
        cout << "All quantities must be positive."<< endl;
        return false;
    }
    else { 
        return true;
    }
}
*/
int func3(int *p, int index){
    
    int currentprice = *(p) * 5 + *(p+1) * 10 + *(p+2) * 15  ;
    return currentprice; 

}

int manin() {
    int budget;
    int num1, num2, num3;
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int p3;
    int currentprice;
    int func3;
    cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 ;
    int position[3] ;
    position[0] = p1 ; 
    position[1] = p2 ; 
    position[2] = p3 ; 
    int *p;
    p= position;
    int func3(currentprice);
    cout << currentprice;
return 0; 
}
```

This is the error I receive :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\noname\onedrive\masaüstü\cs\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\source.cpp(56): error C2086: 'int func3' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\noname\onedrive\masaüstü\cs\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\source.cpp(48) : see declaration of 'func3'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

please can you help me out CPP Masters?

Comment: What are you hoping `int func3(currentprice);` will do in your "`manin`" function?  Your error states that it's unclear what that line is supposed to do.

Comment: Try commenting `using namespace std;`.

Comment: You also have a variable `int func3;`

Comment: Please get rid of the `int` in your `if` statement:  `if (int num1`  You can access parameters without specifying their type, as the type was already stated in the declaration.

Comment: Drew-Dormann there is actually and they are     int currentprice; ,     p= position; I suppose. by the way tanks for your comment.

Comment: @DrewDormann int func3(currentprice); should return calculated currentprice with pointers refers to position array.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's right thank you for your answer. I think I am on it too long to be able to see it.

Answer (score 2):

This ...

> ```
>     int func3;
> ```

... is a declaration of `func3` as a variable of type `int`.  It shadows the file-scope declaration of function `func3()`.

This ...

> ```
>     int func3(currentprice);
> ```

... is *also* a declaration of `func3` (not a function call) on account of the `int` in front.  You may not redeclare local variable `func3` in the same scope, not even if the two declarations designate the same type.

Remove the `int func3;` altogether.  Also remove the `int` from `int func3(currentprice);`.

Comment: @JhonBollinger Thank you for your Answer. I applied your suggestions and where it take me to: 1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\noname\onedrive\masaüstü\cs\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\source.cpp(57): error C2664: 'func3' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int *'
1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Great, @siracemintopçu, I'm glad that the problem you asked about has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

It's beneficial to start with a goal in mind. What are you trying to do is not very clear.

`int func3(int *p, int index)` is function and `int func3` is a variable. That is what your error is about. You can rename the variable to avoid this error.

Also, this is not the correct way to call a function:  `int func3(currentprice);`. First that function takes two parameters instead of one. Second, the return value is not stored anywhere.

Also, a console program will start executing from the `main` function. So `manin` should probably be `main`.

Answer (score 1):

@JohnBollinger @DKS @JohnnyMopp @DrewDormann @ThomasMatthews
Guys, I did fix it with your suggestions it results in success. However, it should take 3 cin(p1,p2,p3) and should cout currentprice İnstead it shows empty consol.
I am adding the new codes below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
/*
bool func1(int budget){
    if( budget < 0 ) {
        cout << "Budget cannot be negative."<< endl; 
        return false; 
    }
    else {
        return true; 
    }
}
bool func2(int num1, int num2, int num3){ 
    if (int num1 < 0 || int num2 < 0 || int num3 < 0 ) {
        cout << "All quantities must be positive."<< endl;
        return false;
    }
    else { 
        return true;
    }
}
*/
int func3(int *p){
    
    int currentprice = *(p) * 5 + *(p+1) * 10 + *(p+2) * 15  ;
    return  currentprice; 

}









int main() {
    /*
    int budget;
    int num1, num2, num3;
    */
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int p3;
    int currentprice= 0;
    cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 ;
    int position[3] ;
    position[0] = p1 ; 
    position[1] = p2 ; 
    position[2] = p3 ; 
    int *p;
    p= position;
    func3(p);
    cout << currentprice;
return 0; 
}
```